# PERL: stop and restart parent process without killing child

Tags: perl

This code download EPG with xmltv grabber and send commands to tvtime (tvtime-command) to display a message (Wait several minutes while EPG updates...) along the bottom of the OSD.

If program tvtime does not running, is useless to display a message in tvtime and i want to stop parent process (send commands to tvtime), without killing child (EPG updates...) and if tvtime will be open later while child not finished (EPG updates...), restart parent process (send commands to tvtime).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

$tmp = new File::Temp( UNLINK => 0 );;

defined(my $pid = fork) or die "Couldn't fork: $!";

#child process
if ($pid == 0) {
    system("tv_grab_fi | tv_sort >> $tmp");
    my $HOME = $ENV{HOME};
    system("mv $tmp $HOME/.xmltv/EPG.xml");
    unlink($tmp);
    exit;
}

use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);

#parent process
while (! waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) {
    system("tvtime-command DISPLAY_MESSAGE \'Wait several minutes while EPG updates...\'");
    sleep 1;
}
```

Thanks

My not smartly solution:

```
#parent process
while (! waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) {
       open(PS, "ps aux | grep \[tv\]time |") || die "Can't open PS: $!\n";
       while ( <PS> ) {
         system("tvtime-command DISPLAY_MESSAGE \'Wait several minutes while EPG updates...\'");
         sleep 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand—what do you mean "only if firefox run"? And where does the child process come in on this?

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense to explain what you're *really* trying to do. Why does your parent-process care whether Firefox is running? What does it mean for your parent-process to "restart"? Also -- Perl is famous for the ease of writing portable code in it, but if you need to examine external processes, you're probably going to hit the limit of that. Do you need this to work on multiple systems, or is there a specific operating system you're targeting?

Comment: Example with firefox is not the best. The real program is tvtime. I want procces parent to send a command to tvtime and if this program will not run is absurd to them be sent a command to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm by no means familiar with this, but I would look into [Perl IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) (Interprocess Communication). The general idea is that the child process signals the parent, which can then kill itself.